# Is it possible to combine default member initialization and delegating constructors?

Tags: c++, constructor, member-initialization

Suppose I have a class

```
class Widget
{
public:
    explicit Widget();
    explicit Widget(int foo, int bar);

private:
    Gadget * gadget_;
    int foo_{42};
    int bar_{13};
}
```

with constructors that use some members (therefore initialization order is important):

```
Widget::Widget()
{
    ComplicatedConstructionStandIn::frobnicate_gadget(&gadget_);
    TheConstructorHasManyLines(foo_, gadget_);
    ItDoesMultipleThings(bar_);
}

Widget::Widget(int foo, int bar)
    : foo_{foo}
    , bar_{bar}
{
    ComplicatedConstructionStandIn::frobnicate_gadget(&gadget_);
    TheConstructorHasManyLines(foo_, gadget_);
    ItDoesMultipleThings(bar_);
}
```

Clearly, the second constructor is code duplication so you would think to delegate !BUT! you can't do that if you also want the default member initialization (`int foo{42};`).
By delegation I mean something like this (does not compile):

```
Widget::Widget(int foo, int bar)
    : foo_{foo}
    , bar_{bar}
    , Widget()
{}
```

Is there an elegant way out of this? Wrapping the body of the constructor in an auxiliary init function is just kicking the question down the line.

Comment: Please post a [mre] that we can copy, paste and test.

Comment: "elegant" is subjective. Given that delegating requires the constructor to be the only entry in the member initializer list imho your original code is already an elegant solution

Comment: Code duplication is to be avoided, but don't be afraid to call the same function twice. I doubt that a more "elegant" solution can require less code. I'd rather initialize `gadget` also in the member initializer list.

Comment: `Gadget* ComplicatedConstructionStandIn::frobnicate_gadget()` <-- something like that would solve this particular example. Then you can use it in the member variable defining declaration `gadget_{ComplicatedConstructionStandIn::frobnicate_gadget()};`

Comment: You need to specify the default somewhere else, but you can go with a single constructor only this way: `explicit Widget(int foo = 42) : foo_(foo){ ComplicatedConstructionStandIn::frobnicate_gadget(&gadget_); }`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Imagine `ComplicatedConstructionStandIn::frobnicate_gadget(&gadget_);` is 50 lines long (as it's name suggests).

Comment: @JanHošek if it's 50 lines long wrap it in a convenience function

Comment: @JanHošek so what? As I said, duplication is not in the function, the duplication is that you call the same function twice, and thats just what functions are made for. In case you mean its not just a function call, but 50 lines in the body of the constructor, then ... place those 50 lines inside a function ;)

Comment: In `Widget` I'd make a private `static std::unique_ptr<Gadget> make_gadget() { /*50 lines*/ }` and use that to *in situ* initialize the member variable `std::unique_ptr<Gadget> gadget_{ make_gadget() };`.  And change the member variable to be a **unique_ptr**.

Comment: Some eager beaver closed this not even ten minutes after asking with vaguely-related "duplicates", neither of which mention default member initializers and while I was in the middle of adding detail to respond to early comments. I don't think this is a bad question and the unique combination of default member initialization and constructor delegation hasn't been asked before AFAICT. Please reopen if only so more discussion can be had. Much worse questions get asked.

Comment: `Widget::Widget(int foo = 42, int bar = 13)`.